# Button to trigger another VC, Navigation Controller Back Button not showing in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I've got 3 VC. 1. Root VC, Register VC and Login VC.

First, I created the buttons and linked them to the desired VC by Show(e.g. Push). Then, at the Root VC, I clicked on Embeded in Navigation Controller. All the Back Button showed at the correct VC as shown in the pic below.

But when I run the simulator, the back buttons are all missing.

I have tried naming all the segues but it is not working.

I am not sure where I have done wrong, please help

[image: Story Board]

[image: Simulator 1]

[image: Simulator 2]

[image: Full storyboard]

News.m the InitView Controller

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

if(![(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] authenticated]) {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    RootViewController *initView =  (RootViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initialView"];
    [initView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:initView animated:NO completion:nil];
} else{
    // proceed with the profile view
  }
 }
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize loginView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
  - (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(loginActionFinished:)
                                               name:@"loginActionFinished"
                                           object:loginView];

  }


 #pragma mark - Dismissing Delegate Methods

 -(void) loginActionFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {

AppDelegate *authObj = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
authObj.authenticated = YES;

[self dismissLoginAndShowProfile];
}

- (void)dismissLoginAndShowProfile {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
    [self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil];
}];


}

@end
```

Comment: Looks like your navigation bar is set to hidden.

Comment: from screenshot , your navigation controller is not root view controller (-> Arrow is missing )

Comment: I can't set it as a init coz I have another VC that will check if user is register, if not register then it will come to this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

As per the discussion in the comment, the solution seems like the following:

Create a Subclass of `UINavigationController`, say `RootNavigationController`.

```
class RootNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    ....
}
```

[image]

Now if the user is not registered, route them to `RootNavigationController` by setting it rootviewcontroller in `AppDelegate`:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootNavigationControllerID")

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In the screenshot, RootViewController is your Root VC.

### Original Answer

From your questions and screenshots it seems like your navigation controller is not your root view controller.

1. You can set your `NavigationController` as initial view controller from storyboard like this:

[image]

2. If you've set `RootViewController` from code, you can set it from `AppDelegate` like this:

   ```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstNavigationController")

   self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   ```

Comment: But I can't set it to initialViewController. At my NewsVC, I check if user is authenticated, if not I will ask user to register.

Comment: Okay, whenever you're going to your `RootViewController`, don't push to RootViewController, rather push to your `NavigationController`

Comment: Sorry Arnab, I don't really understand but eager to hear you out. If user is not registered, they will be routed to my RootVC, and at RootVC I have 2 buttons. 1 button is to RegisterVC and another button is to LoginVC.

Comment: "If user is not registered, they will be routed to my RootVC"... that's what i'm saying, not to route them to RootVC. Create a subclass of `UINavigationController`, and route to that navigationControllerSubClass, whose `RootViewController` is set to RootVC, I guess

Comment: How do I create a subclass of UINavigationConroller at RootViewController.m?

Comment: Keep `RootViewController.m` as it is, just modify the NavigationController as the answer i just edited

Comment: My pleasure, Hansheung